# Присвоение значения вектору vhdl

Tags: микроконтроллеры, vhdl

Как можно переписать эту строчку так чтобы присвоить другое значение вида `'10101101101...100110'`

```
signal key1_in : std_logic_vector(0 to 63) := (others => '0');
```

Comment: а что это за строка?

Comment: это код на vhdl

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите присвоить значение сигналу на этапе инициализации, то так же и пишите, при условии, что однобитные значения в одинарных кавычках, а шины в двойных

`signal key1_in : std_logic_vector(0 to 63) := "10101101101...100110";`

Answer (score 0):

Можете ваше число представить в десятичный вид и присвоить значение, пусть ваше число 1234, тогда
Подключим библиотеку 
Use ieee.std_logic_arith.all

А наше присвоение будет

Signal key1_in:std_logic_vector(0 to 63):= conv_std_logic_vector(1234,64);